# Relate data for creating a PivotTable with multiple worksheets

Tags: excel, excel-2013

I have an Excel file with 51 worksheets. Each worksheet has a table with four columns: Image, Year, City, Result (same header for all the worksheets) and multiple rows ranging between 100k - 1M rows:

- The column 'Image' has a unique entry for each row which is nothing
  but image name.
- The column 'Year' ranges between 1900-2000 and could be any year for 
  a given image. (Same for all the tables.)
- The column 'Result' has one of the three entries (good, bad, NA) for
  each image. (Same for all the tables.)
- The column 'City' has multiple city names where a given city would
  have multiple images tagged to it. (Same for all the tables.)

I want to create a PivotTable with rows as year and columns as good, bad, NA, total with which I should be able to get the information such as a particular year has 'X' number of images from 51 worksheets of which 'i' are `Good`, 'j' are `Bad` and 'k' are `NA`.

How can I create a relation between data so that I can achieve this?

Comment: @pnuts : No, i don't.

Comment: There are gonna be multiple users viewing/editing this data in different computers. If every user needs to download PowerPivot then i guess i can't use it. Otherwise i'm totally up for it.